# mysqlslap access denied on windows8

Tags: mysql, windows

i'm getting access deniedwhen trying to run mysqlslap, and i'm suspecting it has something to do with me running on a windows 8.1 machine, but i can't confirm it anywhere.

the line i'm trying to run is

```
mysqlslap.exe --query="myquery" --iterations=10 --user=root -p=password --host=127.0.0.1 --delimiter=";" --create-schema=mydb
```

i've tried running -p without the password to get prompted for the password, but i get access denied before ever getting prompted for a password.

i've tried with and without the --host, --delimiter and --password

besides the error on the command prompt i get a popup from windows saying that this app cannot run on my pc. searching for mysqlslap and windows 8 didn't help much.

i confirmed my password by logging into mysql via commandpropt with user root and the password I passed as an argument to mysqlslap

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

1. Open CMD([here](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window) is a link showing how to do).
2. In CMD enter in MySQL Bin Folder like "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin".(to open folder in cmd use comand "cd" or "cd.." to back a folder, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z21iLsS_VUw) is a link showing how todo do)
3. So enter with comand: `mysqlslap --create-schema=yourschema --query="your query" --concurrency=100 -uuser -ppassword`

Comment: Why do you think this solves the problem? Please elaborate by editing your answer.

Comment: I think Windows 8 with MySQLSlap have a problem with parameters. I tried with "--" and doesn't worked, so I tried with parameters "-" and worked!!

Comment: Which parameters do you mean? `-u` and `-p`? I think you missed a space between those parameters and their values.

Comment: Parameters -u and -p don't need space. I think the problem of KristianMedK is the comand "mysqlslap.exe". The right command is only "mysqlslap", so I edited my answer.

Comment: mysqlslap.exe or mysqlslap is completely irrelevant on windows. Both can be used. Shouldn't this be `mysqlslap --create-schema=yourschema --query="your query" --concurrency=100 -u user -p password`?

Comment: You are right Artjom B, but the comand "-p=password" of KristianMedK is wrong -, if everbody follow my answer or your comment are able to use mysqlslap